# How do I create a new log file if my current log file is larger than 50mb in php?

Tags: php

I have a project where I have to make a new log file if the current log file is larger than 50mb. I know that we have to test for the size of the file.

I am starting out with this $log variable:

```
$log  = 
    "Branch: ".$branchDir . PHP_EOL.
    "Phase: ". $phaseDir . PHP_EOL.
    "Total number of results files deleted: ". count($folderCounter). PHP_EOL.
    "File names: " . $filePathToDelete . PHP_EOL.
    "Starting CustomerID directory name: " . $CustIDvalue . PHP_EOL;
    // $log = 'this is a test' . $branch . PHP_EOL;
$dt = time();
$mysql_datetime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $dt);
$mysql_datetimes = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $mysql_datetime);
$logFileName = "ResultsFileDeletion" . $mysql_datetimes . ".txt";



   if (unlink($filePathToDelete)) {
//this echo string will be moved to a log file
    echo "first unlink: {$filePathToDelete} was deleted <br>";
    $myFile = 
      file_put_contents("c:\\sites\\EtonBio/sequencing/logs/{$logFileName}", 
      $log, FILE_APPEND);
    echo 'my file: ' . $myFile . '<br>';
    }
```

I found this code snippet:

```
$size = filesize($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']);
```

I believe my if statement would look something like this:

```
    if($size < 52428800) {
*creates another log file
}
```

I want to format the $size variable correctly and I am also not sure how to make a new log file.

Comment: Deleting a log file is bad practice - why collect the data if you're only going to throw it away? Its a better idea to rename the file (and delete older files). You also need to force any process with an open file handle on the file to close it before you delete it (although MSWindows tends to be heavy-handed with locking).

Comment: I never mentioned deleting a log file. I am trying to **split** the file if it is over 50 mb. I am not sure if this is done before or after actually logging the file.

Comment: Did you read the code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

`$size = filesize($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']);` only works if you are uploading the file.
If you want to check a file already in you server ou can simply do

```
 $size = filesize("path/to/file");
```

Also, there is a `'` in your `$log` declaration that shouldn't be there

Comment: Thank you for noticing that '. I am trying to create log files, but if is is larger than 50mb, then I would have to split it into another log file. I'm not sure if that makes sense or not?

Comment: Thank you! I am having difficulty finding out what to put in that if statement though. Do you mind helping me out with that?